# CakePHP fopen failed to open stream permission denied

Tags: cakephp, permissions, xampp

CakePHP version 1.74

PHP version 5.3.5

Installed to xampp on windows 10.

---

Recently, I am getting permission denied error messages and it seems that they are all related with "tmp\cache" folder. There are Everone(Group), System, Youn(admin user) and Administrators(Group) assigned to this folder with full control and I recently assigned IUSER, Users Group but still having same issues.

Error messages are slightly different each time but all related with "tmp\cache" folder. One strange thing I found is this error does not effect anything to this program. Error messages is gone after refreshing the page and program is working fine as normal.

Error Message
fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\epic\app\tmp\cache\models\cake_model_default_vendors) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE\cake\libs\cache\file.php, line 142]

Please advise me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz6kh.jpg)

Comment: Those are incredibly old versions of Cake and PHP, long since stopped receiving any security updates. If this is something you're running into while updating the application to new versions of these things, then just ignore it. If it's something you're running into in a brand new application, then please restart with Cake 4 and PHP 8. If it's something you've been tasked with maintaining, you should push whoever asked you to do this to update it instead. If that's absolutely not an option, then check what user the web server (Apache or IIS) is running under, and make sure it has permissions.

Comment: User and Group are set to Demon. How can I assign permission to demon for "tmp\cache" folder?